# tring to understand some codes which is related to array_reverse in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
class ExtendedArrayObject extends ArrayObject {
    private $_array;
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (is_array(func_get_arg(0)))
            $this->_array = func_get_arg(0);
        else
            $this->_array = func_get_args();
        parent::__construct($this->_array);
    }

    public function reverse($applyToSelf=false)
    {
        if (!$applyToSelf)
        {
            return array_reverse($this->_array);
        }
        else
        {
            $_array = array_reverse($this->_array);
            $this->_array = $_array;
            parent::__construct($this->_array);
            return $this->_array;
        }
    }
}
$newArray = new ExtendedArrayObject(array(1,2,3,4,5,6));
print_r($newArray->reverse()); //reverse the array
...
?>
```

Above code is taken from a book.

Question:

I changed the code to `print_r($newArray->reverse(true));`
but the output is the same. so since the output is the same, why we need to use if...else...?  in which case, why we need this else part?

Thanks.

Comment: You have some kind of mistake inside the else { } statement.. Currently its pointless to call parent::__construct on nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its to do with mutable state.

The else part allows a return value of a reverese array while leaving the original array in the original order

```
<?php
$newArray1 = new ExtendedArrayObject(array(1,2,3,4,5,6));
$revArray1 = $newArray->reverse();

print_r($newArray1); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
print_r($revArray1); // 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

$newArray2 = new ExtendedArrayObject(array(1,2,3,4,5,6));
$revArray2 = $newArray->reverse(true);

print_r($newArray2); // 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
print_r($revArray2); // 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The output LOOKS the same, but it's radically different.

try this instead of the current print_r:

```
print_r($newArray);
print_r($newArray->reverse());
print_r($newArray);
print_r($newArray->reverse(true));
print_r($newArray);
```

See? it's very different!

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that for false case the reversed array is not assigned to the private variable `$_array`. For the true case it is assigned.

```
$array = new ExtendedArrayObject(array(1,2,3,4,5,6));

//false case
$reversed_array1 = $array->reverse();
var_dump($reversed_array1);//6,5,4,3,2,1
var_dump($array);//1,2,3,4,5,6

//true case
$reversed_array2 = $array->reverse(true);
var_dump($reversed_array2);//6,5,4,3,2,1
var_dump($array);//6,5,4,3,2,1
```

Answer (score 0):

With `$applyToSelf`, your array is permanently changed, so if you reference it later in the program you will be using the reversed array.

Without `$applyToSelf`, it is not, so you're just returning a reversed array for a single use.